# How do static objects work?

Tags: java, object, static

I know how to work with objects.. but one thing in particular has me scratching my head.
Static methods.

I'll give an example.

```
Toolkit theKit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
```

I think that the `theKit` object now holds `new Toolkit();` class.. but im not sure.

Furthermore I can do `theKit.getScreenResolution();` now with `theKit` reference variable.

Is that because `Thetoolkit` class it self contains that method?

Forgive me, now that I wrote it all out it seems obvious but ill ask anyway. Thank you.

Comment: you answer to own question..Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit() is equivalent to new Toolkit(); It is like singleton

Comment: @Arun not necessary (you can have `foo(); ... bar(); return new Toolkit();`) inside that black-box method.

Comment: @Arun "equivalent" is not the right word. There's a lot more going on in that method than just `return new Toolkit()`.

Comment: @everything is possible but as naming convention of method its seem to be returning unique instance

Comment: @Arun talking about naming convention, it almost never (except one, very first call) do `new Toolkit();`

Comment: @om-nom-nom as i said everything is possible...yes you are right you can initialize any static content of the class...with such methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a design patten. Now given the case, it is necessary that the `Toolkit` remains singleton.
So the library designer made sure that it remains singleton by itself providing a method to `getDefaultToolkit`.

`getDefaultToolkit` returns a `Toolkit` which can be used by the library users.

Now to provide access to such a method, given one cant initialize `Toolkit` by 'new Toolkit()`, the library provides a static method, which gives access to it

Comment: Not necessarily a singleton.

Comment: Yes. But `Toolkit` is a singleton. And hence the method is used to return it

Comment: Actually, this answer describes it the best.. because I really had trouble understanding why I'd use a static method for this particular case.

Answer (score 5):

`static` methods belong to the class. Not the instance.
Same is with all `static` member variables.
So you don't need to create an instance of an object to use the method. Since it belongs to the class you just access it via the class name.
A common usage for `static` methods is utility methods. You don't use an object (and it might not make sense for a concrete object to exist in your design of class hierarchy) and so you access the method via the class

Answer (score 1):

I can have a static method that indeed creates an instance of a class. Static methods doesn't belongs to an instance but to the class itself so you don't need to have an instance of a class to use its static methods. Simple example:

```
public class MyClassExample(){

public static MyClassExample getDefaultInstance(){
 return new MyClassExample();
}

}
```

Then you can instantiate MyClassExample this way:

```
MyClassExample example = MyClassExample.getDefaultInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Toolkit theKit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
```

The above line is a `factory` technique to get the Class instance and `getDefaultToolkit()` is a factory method and it is obviously a static method(so you are calling directly using class name) which will return the instance of the class(in your case it is Toolkit class).We also use this technique in case of singleton.

And regarding your question, yes as the class contains the method getScreenResolution(), so you are able to call it and it is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()` is a static factory helper method to get instance of ToolKit class. The 'theKit' is a valid instance and you can use it the same way you use when you create object instance with new. Having such helper method is best practice as mentioned in effective java book '*Consider static factory methods instead of constructors*'

Answer (score 1):

The method `getDefaultToolkit()` is `static` which means that you don't need an instantiated object of the `Toolkit` class to access this method. When the class is known to the JVM, it is there and the static method can be accessed at all times. This is because they will never change! They will not alter their state, they will never do something else but return a `Toolkit`Object in this case.

And here I said it. Internally I am guessing that the method `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()` does something like this :

```
public Toolkit getDefaultToolkit(){
   return new Toolkit();   
}
```

Well this would be too easy, but somewhere within that static method an Object will be created and returned.

So afterwards your variable `theKid` actually holds the reference to a real  `Object`. A non static instance, that can change and do things.. for example with the method `theKit.getScreenResolution()` it can give you the resolution of the current screen.. Not just *a* resolution.. but *the exact* resolution (which changes on every device with every screen)– meaning this method cannot be static, but needs an Object.